# Подсчет положительных элементов в матрице

Tags: c, алгоритм

Как мне подсчитать кол-во положительных элементов? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Уж проще некуда! Что не получается?

Comment: не знаю с чего начать... как сравнить? через if?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Матрица - m[column][row]

`int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
     if(m[i][j] > 0){
        count++;
     }
  }
}`

Как-то так